# Fail to read JSON via JsonUtility

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I'm pulling Json data from my server and intending to read it into a profile.
The code runs right up to the  `userProfile1 = JsonUtility.FromJson<UserProfile>(www.text);` and stops. I tried putting a debug line before and after and the after debug never fires.

I think the issue perhaps has something to do with how Unity's JsonUtility expects the data format to be, but I'm not sure exactly what as I get no error back.

```
string baseurl = "http://55.55.55.55/api/";
public string loginId = "test@spam.com";
public UserProfile userProfile1;

void Start()
{
    userProfile1 = new UserProfile();    
    StartCoroutine(GetUserProfile(loginId));
}

IEnumerator GetUserProfile(string email)
{
    string url = baseurl + "users/email/" + email;

    // Call server
    WWW www = new WWW(url);

    yield return www;

    // Read returned user profile
    if (www.error == null)
    {
        userProfile1 = JsonUtility.FromJson<UserProfile>(www.text);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("WWW Error: " + www.error);
    }
}
```

Here's the class for the profile:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class UserProfile
{
    public string _id;
    public string first_name;
    public string last_name;
    public string email;
    public string nick;
    public string join_date;
    public int age;
    public string sex;
    public int inventory_slot;
    public int __v;
}
```

Here's the Json data from the server as grabbed by `www.text`

```
[
    {
        "_id":"58b92a058f9565e76d364437",
        "first_name":"Test",
        "last_name":"Name",
        "email":"tinkle@spam.com",
        "nick":"Tinkle",
        "age":42,
        "sex":"male",
        "__v":0,
        "inventory_slot":200000,
        "join_date":"2017-02-26T00:36:10.266Z"
    }
]
```

Comment: This is a json **array** being sent by the server. Do `string myJson = www.error;` then fix  the json to work with `JsonHelper` by doing: `myJson = fixJson(myJson);`. Now, you can do `UserProfile[] userProfile1 = JsonHelper.FromJson<UserProfile>(myJson );`

Comment: . You can find both the `fixJson` function and the `JsonHelper` class on the answer provided in the duplicated question.

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with your model. I don't think the `www.text` has a value at all. It's probably still `null`, because the data hasn't arrived. I suggest what you should do is this:

```
IEnumerator GetUserProfile(string email, Action<string> complete)
    {
        string url = baseurl + "users/email/" + email;
        // Call server
        WWW www = new WWW(url);
        yield return www;
        complete(www.text);
    }
```

And you should change your StartCoroutine to this:

```
 StartCoroutine(GetUserProfile(loginId, (data) =>
                    {
              var userProfile1 = JsonUtility.FromJson<UserProfile>(data);
  }));
```

Hope it helps!

**P.S.** Or you know what, I'm starting to think that the problem is that you're passing a List. Try changing `JsonUtility.FromJson<UserProfile>(data)` to `JsonUtility.FromJson<List< UserProfile>>(data)`.